# Having trouble detirming out to convert raw RFID data to usable string

Tags: python, hex, rfid

I have this http://www.parallax.com/Portals/0/Downloads/docs/prod/audiovis/28140-28340-RFIDreader-v2.2.pdf RFID reader connected to a raspberry pi. I have tried to get the ID using Java and Python. I am able to get output from both but cannot decipher what the data is and now to convert it into the actual ID.

Java code: http://stephenjam.es/wp/wp-content/uploads/java/RFIDReaderBasic.java

Java Output: 
0xc2 0xbd 0xc3 0x99 0xc2 0xae 0xc3 0xb6 0x76 0xc3 0x96 0x56 0x45 0xc2 0x8b 0x6b 0x56 0x00

I think this is hex but I can't tell.

Python Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 2400, timeout=1)
while True:
    string = ser.read(12)
    if len(string) == 0:
        print "Please insert a tag"
        continue
    else:
        print string
```

Python Output:
?ٮ?v?VE?kV

I would rather use python, but am willing to use the java code I got from that website as well. My biggest question is where to start, am I converting Hex to ascii, hex to decimal or what?

Answer (score 0):

May be the baud_rate is wrong. That's why it is printing garbage. Check the default baud_rate of your RFID reader. May be it's 4800 or 9600.